Legality of putting up flyers in an airport?
I have produced a product, and I intend on using flyers to advertise it. I am considering putting some up in airports in Austin and Chicago, but I don't know if I am allowed to. Is there like a bulletin board at airports? Or can I pay shopowners to put up my flyers in their shops?

Ask the airport manager.

Have you ever seen a flyer posted in a major airport? I'm pretty sure I haven't. There's probably a reason for it, and it's not because you're the first person to think of it.

The airports rent spaces to various shops.

The rental contracts will almost certainly regulate what the shops can sell and advertise, just as for any other shopping mall. A shop cannot suddenly switch from books to pizza if there is another pizza shop next door.
The local shop managers are almost all part of a franchise or employees of a larger company. That means they are also not free in what they do, one would have to ask their company management.

There are large companies managing the advertising in various airports. You can rent space from them, but it might be much more expensive than you expect.
